# Pharo - Image with Seaside in it is stuck, can't click on anything in the UI?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Pharo - Image with Seaside in it is stuck, can't click on anything in the UI?

The app is fine, I can access it through the web interface. What can I do?

It's an old Pharo 1.3 Seaside 3.0.7 developer image from here:
http://www.seaside.st/distributions/Seaside-3.0.7-final.zip
http://www.seaside.st/download/pharo

Later edit: looking at http://localhost:8080/status

[image: Printscreen of the localhost status]

Later edit: Terminated both of them.
[image: After I terminated 13133... and 100348...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `alt+.` (Linux) or `cmd+.` (OS X). That should trigger a user interrupt and open a debugger (you'll possibly need to hit the key combo a few times in row).

The older Seaside version also used to have a facility to suspend and resume the UI process through the web interface exposed via `/seaside/config`. Not sure if that is still available.

Comment: Can't see anything like that on http://localhost:8080/seaside/config my Seaside is 3.0.7 so not that old, maybe it was taken out in version 3. The cmd+. does absolutely nothing. Also read this http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2010-December/036674.html  and tried the http://localhost:8080/status and this works, I can see processes and the lot.

Comment: Added a print screen with the http://localhost:8080/status to the original question.

Comment: Ok. Managed to get my code out piece by piece through the Seaside Halos and the build in code browser. Still... the image seems fine all but the actual UI. One more thing, if I try to resize the Pharo window on my mac the VM just quits.

Comment: There are two processes in the same method that may be deadlocking each other (13133... and 100348...). You could try terminating both (they're just some UI related processes AFAIC) or signal the semaphore for one of them and see if that resolves the deadlock.

Comment: Terminated both of them and added a screenshot of that. UI is still non responsive. One thin to note, if I Signal 100348... both 13133... and 100348... disappear and I something similar to the terminated screen shot. Signaling 13133... produces nothing really. UI still non responsive in both cases.